# How do I load psutil.cpu_percent average for each process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, psutil

I'm trying to load the cpu averages for all process id's on a host using the following snippet of code:

```
import psutil

while True:
    for pid in psutil.pids():
        p = psutil.Process(pid)
        cpu_p = float(p.cpu_percent())
        if cpu_p == float(100.0)
            break
        elif cpu_p > float(0.0):
            print(cpu_p)
```

The problem is that the results keep returning 0.0 result. In the psutil docs, it states (ref: https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#functions):

```
Warning: the first time this function is called with interval = 0.0 
or None it will return a meaningless 0.0 value which you are supposed 
to ignore.
```

How do I create a proper return value for seeking cpu_percentage in a loop instead of constantly returning a 0.0?

Comment: I've also tried cpu_percent(interval=0.1), but the results don't seem to be too accurate with what I'm seeing in `top`.